# SQL sum row with condition id of row

Tags: c#, sql

SQL server 2008.
I have table:

```
ID         note       valueA        valueB     isCondition    condition
1          SumA         ?              ?         True          2+3+4
2          A.1          5              6         False
3          A.2          5              6         False
4          A.3          5              6         False
5          SumB         ?              ?         True          2+3
6          B.1          ?              ?         False
```

So, I want sum Rows that is has conditions?

Comment: show us your code, where you tried to solve it

Comment: sum rows??? you want 2+3+4+2+3 or SumA , SumB.

Comment: There is no chance to help you so far... Please poste the expected result and how you do the calculation. I have no idea which values you want to sum up...

Comment: I want get row "SumA", that values of column valueA is sum by condition "ID 2 + ID 3+ ID 4".

Comment: I have code in c# but i want to do it on SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (id int,splitdata int)

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitdata] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) ,
    @CurrentId int
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO #tmp  VALUES(CurrentId,SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END

--------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT ID from TableName as a CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplitdata(a.Condition,'+',a.ID) as b
```

--Split COndition into multiple rows with ID
--Taking that data into temporary table
--e.g. 
-- 1 2
-- 1 3

```
update T1 set a.ValueA=(select sum(ValueA) from TableName join #tmp on TableName.ID=#tmp.splitdata and T1.ID=#tmp.id) from TableName T1 where IsCOndition=1 and Note='SumA'

update T1 set a.ValueA=(select sum(ValueB) from TableName join #tmp on TableName.ID=#tmp.splitdata and T1.ID=#tmp.id) from TableName T1 where IsCOndition=1 and Note='SumB'
```

Code is not compiled..make the chages as required...

Comment: Thanks! Great Code. Cảm ơn rất nhiều.